# Lollipop - Google Play Services is murdering my battery when roaming

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-touchwiz

I'm on vacation in America, and ever since I got here, my Samsung Galaxy S5 running stock Lollipop (no updates pending) has been burning through its battery at about 1% per minute (with the screen off). The phone gets crazy-hot to the touch (chassis, not battery) and the culprit is Google Play Services according to the Battery screen.
I've looked up some advice articles that recommend disabling GPS (I switched Locations off completely), uninstalling recent apps (done, and then some) and uninstalling updates to Play Services itself (which I can't do on my Samsung device, all the buttons are greyed out).
The phone was working okay when I left the UK. When I landed and switched flight mode off, the device was utterly unusable for 5 minutes straight. I ended up disabling background data sync to get some kind of stability. However, it still gets to the point that the keyboard lags some seconds behind my taps, and swipe is totally unusable.
I'm struggling to work out exactly what's causing this, because switching off features only seems to buy me a short reprieve. I've never seen battery life this bad back home, but equally, I've never seen a phone annihilate its battery like this while roaming. What else can I try?
(I should mention that my plan from the UK allows me to use my data allowance when roaming, so this is not costing me any money)

Edit: upon returning to the UK, my battery life appears to have returned to normal. Something about being out of the country was causing the CPU to go crazy.